# Localizing country code not in xcode's list and others not working

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, localization

I am trying to add the localization for Tagalog (Philippines) which is listed as `tl` [here](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/English_list.php) for its country code, but it's not in Xcode 4.5's big list of languages. So how do I add it?
If I just add the `tl.lproj` folder to my code, will it just work even though it doesn't show up in the list of Localizations? Or should I add it somewhere else, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put content (such as `Localizable.strings`) in a tl.lproj folder in your project's directory then add that content to your project.

Comment: Thanks. So even if xcode doesn't show it as an added language it'll work?

Comment: As I remember from an Apple Dev Video that should work that way. BTW u can call an app with something like /.myAppsBinary -AppleLanguages "(zh-TW)" to start it with that language.

Answer (score -1):

If you search for Tagalog in Settings > General > Language & Region > iPhone Language it's not there even in iOS 9. Same for Kurdish and Flemish. So why would manually adding the tl.proj work if users can't even select those languages?

If Xcode doesn't list it, it's probably for a reason...